# error in calculating derivative

Tags: r, for-loop, derivative

Colleagues, I have the table with two columns - `y` and `x` with values of this variables:

```
y    x

4    3

5    3.5

6.5  4.5

7.6  5.2

9.9  7.4
```

I need to calculate the second derivative of this function that is determined by table form.
I know that the approximation of second derivative is:

(y_(i-1)-2y_i + y_(i+1))/((x_i-x_i-1)^2)

And I want to result the vector of second derivative for each x_i and after that I want to print this vector.

F.e. in point `x=3.5` the second derivative is `(4-2*5+6.5)/((3.5-3)^2)`

My input data is `df=data.frame (y,x)` and `k`- number of column, where the argument of function (x - column) is. But my function does not work.

```
My_fun=function(data,k) {
d1=data[,k] #to get the column with x
d2=data[-k] #to get the column with y
for(i in 2:(nrow(data)-1)) {
c1=(d2[i-1]-d[i]+d[i+1])/((d1[i]-d[i-1])^2)
}
c(NA,c1,NA) #because for first and last element we can not calculate it
}
```

Comment: 1 - Check types of `d1` and `d2`. One is a vector, the other a `data.frame` (use `as.numeric` on both of them). 2 - In your loop, you have a variable called `d` which is not defined (use `d1` or `d2`). 3 - You are replacing value of `c1` at each iteration since you are not using an index. Consider defining `c1` before your loop (`c1 = rep(NA,nrow(data))`) and then use an index `c1[i]` in your loop.